# How to create an entity's relationship to itself? For example, hierarchical folders

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to create a hierarchical folder structure.  Here's my Folder entity:

```
$ yo jhipster:entity Folder
The entity Folder is being created.
Generating field #1
? Do you want to add a field to your entity? Yes
? What is the name of your field? name
? What is the type of your field? String
? Do you want to add validation rules to your field? No
=================Folder=================
name (String)
Generating field #2
? Do you want to add a field to your entity? Yes
? What is the name of your field? parentId
? What is the type of your field? Long
? Do you want to add validation rules to your field? No
=================Folder=================
name (String)
parentId (Long)
Generating field #3
? Do you want to add a field to your entity? No
=================Folder=================
name (String)
parentId (Long)
```

I'm trying to map out just what I need to provide jhipster's entity generator to make it work.  This is what I have so far...

```
Generating relationships with other entities
? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? Yes
? What is the name of the other entity? Folder
? What is the name of the relationship? parent
? What is the type of the relationship? one-to-many
? What is the name of this relationship in the other entity? child
```

Am I on the right track?  How do I create the child many-to-one relationship?  I get a warning if I try to create it with the Folder entity.  There's no way to generate it afterwards.

Comment: Interesting question. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/ for writing as jdl for creating entities.
Please visit https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-uml/#jdl for more information.
This is a sample JDL that has relationship to itself :

```
entity RankProperties {
    rank Integer required,
    minExp Integer required,
    maxExp Integer required,
    maxStamina Integer required,
    maxAlly Integer required,
    maxTeam Integer required    
}
enum TaskMode {
    NO_CONTINUE_STAGE_COUNT,
    STAGE_COUNT,
    STAGE_ID
}

entity Task {
    taskMode TaskMode required,
    value Integer   required
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Task{parent} to Task
}

dto all with mapstruct
service all with serviceClass
```

Comment: @pierre-henry this is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use **jdl model**.

```
entity A { property1 String }
relationship OneToMany {
   A{sons} to A{parent}
}
```

The model generates a Entity java class like (some annotations ignored):

```
class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<A> sons = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private A parent;
}
```